# rendering 3d lwjgl flat terrain doesn't work

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import  static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWCursorPosCallback;
import   org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;


import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Matrix4f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector4f;
import org.omg.Messaging.SYNC_WITH_TRANSPORT;



public class man {
private static final int VERTEX_COUNT = 128;
private static final float SIZE = 1;
public static int count;
public static int vid;
public static int iid;


public static int program;

public static float fov = 70f;
public static float near = 0.1f;
public static float far = 1000f;

public static Matrix4f modelMatrix = new Matrix4f() ;
public static Matrix4f view = new Matrix4f();

public static Matrix4f projectionmatrix = new Matrix4f();




public static GLFWCursorPosCallback mouseCallback;

public static boolean t = true;
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {

        glfwInit();
        int prog = 0 , id=0;
      long window =  glfwCreateWindow(1920, 
              1080, "HI", 0 , 0);


      glfwShowWindow(window);


      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


      GL.createCapabilities();



    //  glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouseCallback = new mouse());


      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
      {





          glfwSwapBuffers(window);
          glfwPollEvents();

           new man().createShader();
          new man().bind();





        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        glEnable(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
        glEnable(GL_PROJECTION);



        new man().createprojection();
        new man().createview();

        glUseProgram(program);

        new man().loadtoshader();
         glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vid);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT , 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iid);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


      }

    }






    public void createShader() throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder vertex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder  frag = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader vert ,fragment;
        vert = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/work/opengl2/src/opengl2/vertexShader.txt"));
        fragment = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/work/opengl2/src/opengl2/frageShader.txt"));
        //vertex Shader

        String line, line2;
        while ( (line =  vert.readLine()) != null)
        {
            vertex.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        while ( (line2 =  fragment.readLine()) != null)
        {
            frag.append(line2).append('\n');
        }
        //create and comile shaders
            int vertexShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            GL20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertex);
            GL20.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
            int fragmentShader = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            GL20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, frag);
            GL20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
             program = GL20.glCreateProgram();


            GL20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
            GL20.glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);           
            GL20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0 , "postion");


            GL20.glLinkProgram(program);


            if (GL20.glGetProgrami(program, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) != 1)
            {
                System.err.println(GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
                System.exit(1);
            }


            GL20.glValidateProgram(program);

    }



    public void bind()
    {

        float[] vertices = new float[128 * 128 * 3];
        int[] indices = new int[6*(VERTEX_COUNT-1)*(VERTEX_COUNT-1)];


     //generaete terrain 



        int vertexPointer = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<VERTEX_COUNT;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<VERTEX_COUNT;j++){
                vertices[vertexPointer*3] = (float)j/((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;
                vertices[vertexPointer*3+1] = 0;
                vertices[vertexPointer*3+2] = (float)i/((float)VERTEX_COUNT - 1) * SIZE;

                vertexPointer++;
            }
        }
        int pointer = 0;
        for(int gz=0;gz<VERTEX_COUNT-1;gz++){
            for(int gx=0;gx<VERTEX_COUNT-1;gx++){
                int topLeft = (gz*VERTEX_COUNT)+gx;
                int topRight = topLeft + 1;
                int bottomLeft = ((gz+1)*VERTEX_COUNT)+gx;
                int bottomRight = bottomLeft + 1;
                indices[pointer++] = topLeft;
                indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
                indices[pointer++] = topRight;
                indices[pointer++] = topRight;
                indices[pointer++] = bottomLeft;
                indices[pointer++] = bottomRight;
            }
        }



    //end generate terrain

        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        buffer.put(vertices);
        buffer.flip();

        count = indices.length ;

         vid = GL15.glGenBuffers();
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vid);
         GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);



         iid = GL15.glGenBuffers();
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iid);
         IntBuffer indbuf = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
         indbuf.put(indices);
         indbuf.flip();

         GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indbuf, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    }



    public void createprojection()
    {

        float aspect = (float) 1920/1080;

        float y_scale = (float) (1/Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov/2f)));
        float x_scale = y_scale / aspect;
        float frustum_length = far - near;

        projectionmatrix.m00 = x_scale;
        projectionmatrix.m11 = y_scale;
        projectionmatrix.m22 = -((far + near) / frustum_length);
        projectionmatrix.m23 = -1;
        projectionmatrix.m32 = -((2 * near * far) / frustum_length);
        projectionmatrix.m33 = 0;

    }

    public void createview()
    {

        Vector3f modelPos = null;
        Vector3f modelAngle = null;
        Vector3f modelScale = null;
        Vector3f camera = new Vector3f(0,1f,-2f);

        modelPos = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
        modelAngle = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
        modelScale = new Vector3f(1, 1, 1);



        modelMatrix.setIdentity();
        Matrix4f.scale(modelScale, modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
        Matrix4f.translate(modelPos, modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(modelAngle.z), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), 
                modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(modelAngle.y), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), 
                modelMatrix, modelMatrix);
        Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(modelAngle.x), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), 
                modelMatrix, modelMatrix);



            Matrix4f.translate(camera, view, view);




    }



    public void loadtoshader()
    {

        int loc1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection"); 

        FloatBuffer matrixx  = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        projectionmatrix.store(matrixx);
        matrixx.flip();

            glUniformMatrix4fv(loc1, false,matrixx);

            int loc2 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "view"); 

            FloatBuffer matrixx2  = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
            view.store(matrixx2);
            matrixx2.flip();

            glUniformMatrix4fv(loc2, false,matrixx2);


                int loc3 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "model"); 

                FloatBuffer matrixx3  = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
                modelMatrix.store(matrixx3);
                matrixx3.flip();

                glUniformMatrix4fv(loc3, false,matrixx3);
    }






}






class mouse extends GLFWCursorPosCallback
{

    @Override
    public void invoke(long arg0, double x, double y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(x+ " "+ y );

    }

}
```

Hi guys !
I want to generate a simple flat terrain in lwjgl but this code doesn't produce me anything. I am very new in this chapter so if you can explain why this code does nothing please do it!  I am generating the terrain with the code shared by ThinMatrix , then i upload the vertices to the buffers and then render them in the main game loop . When i compile it , it shows me a black screen. I have searched for a lot of tutorials but I didn't find anything that can help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues with your code:

Issue Number 1:  You are generating a new instance of the `man` class on every iteration of the loop.  Create a single instance of the object outside of the loop and use it in the loop.

Issue Number 2: You are using the old, static pipeline OpenGL.  Following ThinMatrix's tutorials, you should be using OpenGL 3 or newer.  Everything should be going through shaders, rather than using the `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` and the likes of that.

Your program should look something like the following:

`man instance = new man()
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
 {
     RENDER THE TERRAIN HERE
     glfwPoll
     glfwSwapBuffers
     glClear
 }`

If you want some example code, I have a repository [here](https://www.github.com/nickclark2016/Luminos/tree/shader-updates) that should help, as I used to watch ThinMatrix tutorials.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

The vertex shader code *should* read:

`gl_Position = projection * view * model * position;`

Comment: Your link doesn't work. i know this code is very 'dirty' but as i said i am very new , this is not  a project this is just for me to learn. And i am using shders, i have created a projection , view and model matrix and send them to shaders, after  this i multiply them with the position of the vertex . Is there a problem in my generate terrain part? Thx for help!

Comment: The link should work now, my bad.  Here is the direct link to the Terrain class: https://github.com/nickclark2016/Luminos/blob/shader-updates/src/tk/luminos/gameobjects/Terrain.java  Do you mind posting your shader code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code ! But i want to know if there is something bad with my "terrain generation" I mean whe i generate cubes or something else which has 'y' value grater than 0 it generates me it ok. But when just when I want to render this flat terrain with the value of y 0 it doesn't work, I saw in your code that you generate the terrain same way as i do.. so can you help me with this code to make it work please?

Comment: For example even when I have this array of vertices:                                     float[] vertices = new float[]
       {
         -1f, 0, -1f,
          1f ,0 ,-1f,
         1f, 0 , 1f,
         -1f ,0 ,1f
         
       }; It still shows me a black window. I checked my shaders ,  I checked the matrices and they are ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you generating normals?

Comment: No . Are they so important? Can you say me why please?

Comment: They are used to determine how light reacts on a scene, as well as setting the up and down directions of a mesh.  In a single sided mesh, this is extremely important because if the normal points down, you can only see it from below (or at least that is how I understand it).  Have you stopped generating a new shader on each iteration?  I see you say anything with a height of above 0 renders, have you tried setting your terrain height to 1 to see if works?  Also, read up on vertex array objects and buffer objects.  It will help you.

Comment: Also, take a look at my Terrain renderer here.  It might help clear up some of the issues that you have with your rendering pipeline: https://github.com/nickclark2016/Luminos/blob/shader-updates/src/tk/luminos/graphics/render/TerrainRenderer.java

Comment: Ok so now I create them once and my program works even with y being 1f. But it still doesn't work with y being 0 , can you say me please that if I would add the normals this will change something? I am doing all what you did and it still does nothing... is something wrong with my matrices or is just a problem of vertices?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in my own code with a `y` value of 0, so I believe it is an issue with your shaders or matrices.

Comment: You have all my code there. I copy and paste matrices . Shaders are alright. I just process the gl position as you do. I will try to download your code and remove the normals so I can see if they really matter. If this will not work too.. i am gonna suicide. I am fighting with this problem too much time.

Comment: Issue with vertex shader: `gl_Position = projection * view * model * position`

Comment: Where is the issue at that line

Comment: You have it reversed.  It should be like I have it, not the way you have it, which is `gl_Position = position * project * view * model `

Comment: NICK I LOVE U +REP I HOPE YOU WILL DRIVE A LAMBO ONE DAY BRO. Thanks a lot that was the problem. Have a NICE day !!

Comment: No problem! I updated my answer for everyone else to see quickly. Given my solution works, do you mind upvoting my answer and showing it is the proper answer by marking as correct?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My shaders: fragment

```
    #version 330

in vec4 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4 (pos);
}
```

vertex:

```
    #version 330

attribute vec3 postion;

uniform mat4 projection;


uniform mat4 view;

uniform mat4 model;

out vec4 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(postion, 1.0) * projection * view * model;
    pos =  vec4(postion, 1.0) ;

}
```

I have updated my java code so it renders different colors base on the vertex position.